# I'm getting warning "cast to pointer from integer of different size"

Tags: c, pointers, casting, size

I'm getting warning "cast to pointer from integer of different size"

Machine

```
x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Compiler

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

This code gives me the warning.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define __BASE (0xE000E100)

void test(uint8_t n)
{
    int i = n / 32;

    volatile uint64_t * __nvic = ((volatile uint64_t *)(__BASE + 4 * i)); //warnning
}
```

Another code

```
void test2(uint8_t n)
{
    int i = n / 32;

    volatile uint32_t * __nvic = ((volatile uint32_t *)(__BASE + 4 * i)); //warning
}
```

I tried it; it worked.

```
void test3(uint8_t n)
{
    int i = n / 32;

    volatile void * ui64 = (void *)((volatile uint64_t)(__BASE + 4 * i));
    volatile uint32_t * __nvic = (volatile uint32_t *)ui64;
}
```

Why does this code work? I don't know why.

Comment: Casting a 32bit value into a pointer causes a warning because a pointer is 64bit. If you convert the 32bit value into 64bit you don't get the warning because it's the same size as a pointer.

Comment: `__nvic` is not a good variable name. _"identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved [...] If the programmer uses such identifiers, the behavior is undefined"_ - So by choosing that variable name, the whole program has [_undefined behavior_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pointer on your system is apparently 64 bits wide.  So when you cast an expression of type `int` (which is typically 32 bits) to a pointer type you'll get the warning.

In the case where you don't get a warning, the `int` expression is first cast to `uint64_t` (which is the same size as a pointer) and then cast to a pointer type.

Comment: In time, pointers may exceed 64-bit.  Instead of setting the seed for future UB/trouble, use an integer type right-sized for a pointer: `(u)intptr_t`.